# Turborepo set order of execution for dev pipeline

Tags: monorepo, pnpm, turborepo

I have following scenario:

```
/apps
    /api
    /web
/packages
    /shared
```

`api` and `web` have a dependency on `shared`. They are both installed with `workspace: *` using `pnpm`.

My `turbo.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["build/**", ".output/**"]
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false,
    },
  }
}
```

All have a `dev` script which starts up a watcher and hotreload. But the issue is that when I want to run `turbo run dev`, `api` fails to start because `shared` isn't launched yet.

Is there a way to set priority to `shared`?

I can't use `dependsOn` because then it waits on the dev script on `shared` to finish, which it doesn't because its a watcher.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i was fetching similer problem, after some searching i found out You can use `--parallel` flag like this `turbo run dev --parallel`